# Smarty condition on submit

Tags: submit, smarty, conditional-statements

Can i place an **if condition** on a submit button to update an **old variable** to a **new variable** ? It's imperative for me to declare it in my php file? And i'll appreaciate if you can tell me what approach will you use.

Assuming that i have an assigned var and the code will look like this:

```
<!-- {assign var='featured' value=$featured} -->
```

And i want to change or update, both the assigned variable and the value with new ones, what approach should i use and how can i store this in my php file in the case it can't be solely made from smarty template?

```
<!-- {if isset($newfeat) && $newfeat == 1}
{assign var='newfeatured' value=$newfeatured}{/if} --> I want this condition to be executed by pressing a submit button. I'm not much interested on the method and it can be .onclick do this condition above.
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the submit button's value to update depending on the $_POST contents? You can use `$smarty.post` for this

Comment: I dont have any post contents defined in php file, what i want to achieve is to execute that line with a submit button, at the press of the button. Doesnt matter to much the method (via javascript or via ajax) i will polish it later when i learn more about PHP OOP and Smarty.